# tail лог-файла на сервере и nslookup на локальной машине

Tags: linux, ssh

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь сделать скрипт, который забирал бы логи в котором хранятся хост-нэймы с удаленного сервера и делал nslookup на локальной машине хостов из этого лога.

Дошел до такого варианта, но он не работает:

```
for i in $(ssh remotebox tail -f /path/log.log); do nslookup $i; done > lookup.log
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

`tail -f`, по идее, будет «висеть» бесконечно, пока его не остановят.

я бы предложил примерно так:

```
# для первого запуска надо, чтобы фйл со «старым»
# списком хотя бы существовал
touch log.old
# бесконечный цикл
while true; do
  # синхронизировать содержимое файла log.log
  rsync remotehost:/path/log.log log.log
  # отсортировать строки с удалением дубликатов
  # и сохранить как «новую» версию списка
  sort -u log.log > log.new
  # найти новые строки и выполнить для них nslookup
  # результат дописать в lookup.log
  comm -3 -1 log.old log.new | while read i; do nslookup $i >> lookup.log; done
  # сохранить список как «старый» для следующей итерации
  mv log.new log.old
  # «поспать» десять секунд
  sleep 10
done
```

Comment: `tail -f` я хочу использовать по причине того, что в лог-файл в секунду пишется очень большое кол-во строк.

Comment: Также на сервере отсутствует `rsync` и возможность его поставить.

Comment: в таком варианте, как у вас, работать не будет точно. можно, конечно, использовать и `tail -f` (после кардинальной перестройки логики), но если вы надеетесь, что каждая вновь добавленная на удалённой машине строка тут же приведёт к запуску программы nslookup на вашей машине, то я вас разочарую: таким путём этого не добиться.

Comment: *Также на сервере отсутствует rsync* — он и не нужен на сервере. он нужен на той машине, где вы его запускаете.

Comment: вот за комментарий про `tail -f` спасибо! Я примерно на такое и надеялся.

С `rsync`ом не получается, потому что часть серверов на solaris и на них он не работает.

Comment: не зная глобальной стоящей перед вами задачи, можно лишь тыкать пальцем в небо, но, возможно, имеет смысл воспользоваться каким-нибудь протоколом отправки логов на другую машину?

Comment: настройте [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/tag/solaris/) - на solaris это возможно.
[Для ознакомления про rsyslog](http://habrahabr.ru/post/213519/)

Answer (score 0):

Если инструмент не так важен, и можно использовать, например, python, то возможно вам понравится [fabric](https://github.com/fabric/fabric)

Вызов команды на удаленном сервер осуществляется через `run`:

```
run('uname -a')
```

локальной команды через `local`:

```
local('ping {0}'.format(HOST)
```

Результат выполнения команды будет выведен на экран, но можно переопределить это поведение указав свой `stdout`.

Например, для вашей задачи fab-файл будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from fabric.api import task, local, run

class MyOut(object):
    def write(self, ip_adress):
        local('nslookup {0}'.format(ip_adress))

    def flush(self):
        pass

@task
def run_task():
    myout = MyOut()
    run('tailf /path/log.log', stdout=myout)
```

Запуск скрипта выполняется следующим образом:

```
fab run_task
```

Единственное, т.к. `tailf` (как и `tail -f`) выполняются бесконечно, то скрипт никогда не прервется и будет постоянно мониторить ваш файл на наличие изменений.

Прервать выполнение скрипта можно как и любой зависшей программы через `CTRL+C`. Либо можно задать какую-либо дополнительную логику: например, прервать выполнение через 10 минут, либо после обработки 1К адресов

Я показал пример для `tailf`, но можно переделать и для любого другого алгоритма, благо язык позволяет. Например, можно реализовать ту же идею с использованием [rsync](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/contrib/project.html?highlight=rsync#fabric.contrib.project.rsync_project)

Возможно, вам пригодятся какие-либо инструменты из [fabtools](https://fabtools.readthedocs.org/en/0.19.0/index.html).

Почитать о fabric и fabtools и ознакомиться с примерами на русском можно [здесь](http://adw0rd.com/2012/8/14/python-fabric/)