# Асинхронный клиент для SSH

Tags: python, ssh, асинхронность, tornado

Пишу веб-приложение на `tornado` на `python 2.7`. Мне нужна асинхронная библиотека для работы по ssh (paramiko подозреваю, что не подойдёт т.к. там блокирующие операции ввода-вывода, если не прав, то поправьте). Ну и у меня два вопроса:

1. Правильно я понимаю, что если просто вывести в отдельный поток работу по ssh (через paramiko), это не решит проблему?
2. Киньте ссылочку на библиотеку или идею, как реализовать данное?

**UPD:** конкретезирую вопрос: 
Как выполнить ssh команду в контексте обработчика запроса в tornado c помощью библиотеки paramiko?

Comment: Читаем [доки](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.setblocking): *setblocking(blocking): Set blocking or non-blocking mode of the channel... In non-blocking mode, if a recv call doesn’t find any data, or if a send call can’t immediately dispose of the data, an error exception is raised... chan.setblocking(0) is equivalent to chan.settimeout(0);*

Comment: И что конкретно вас интересует? Посмотрите мой [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442935/5079), там получается и обрабатывается ответ от "бесконечной" программы в режиме реального времени, возможно вас устроит такое решение

Comment: Спасибо, если не знать, то трудно было бы найти данное в доке. Меня интересует асинхронный вызов команды. Суть в том, что идёт запрос на сервер, затем выполняется команда по ssh. У вас в ответе показывается бесконечный цикл, не совсем то, что нужно

Comment: вместо общей рекомендации о "асинхронный клиент для SSH", задайте более конкретный вопрос, например: "Как выполнить команду по ssh в контексте запроса к tornado серверу?" (ответом может быть фрагмент кода, который использует paramiko без блокировки сервера).

Comment: @jfs обновил вопрос.